# Select default option not working with Ionic Framework

Tags: html, mobile, html-select, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic Framework.
I would like to enter the first option as the default, but doing it this way does not work.
What can I do?

```
<select ng-model="newSpesaAereo.valuta">
    <option ng-selected="selected">Euro</option>
    <option>Dollaro</option>
    <option>Dollaro canadese</option>
    <option>Sterlina</option>
</select>
```

[image]

If I analyze the page with Google Chrome Developer Utility I watch this.

[image]

If I edit this HTML and I delete the selected row, then Euro is visible.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ng-selected` instead of just selected.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

```
<select ng-model="newSpesaAereo.metodoPagamento">
  <option ng-selected="selected">Carta di credito</option>
  <option>Bancomat</option>
  <option>Contanti</option>
  <option>Altro</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I added more details to my problem.

Comment: Can you try creating a codepen or something where we can see the issue?

Answer (score 14):

Set `ng-selected="true"`.

Example:

```
<option ng-selected="true">Carta di credito</option>
```

Comment: Although this solution does work in this case, it fails in other case. I show (and hide) other form elements based upon the selected value by default. Although the ng-selected="true" shows the selected value by default, it fails to show the other form elements that are connected with this selected option. So if you are looking for a similar functionality as mine, I suggest to try out the solution provided by @lisimba.gilkes as it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 10):

The reason the default option isn't working is because, in your controller, you've likely initialised your form model like so:

```
$scope.newSpesaAereo = {}
```

If you want to set default form options, you should also set them in the form model. For example, set 'valuta' to 'Euro' like so:

```
 $scope.newSpesaAereo = { valuta: "Euro" }
```

I hope this helps!

P.S when posting issues like this you should also include the code for the controller that the view is bound to.

Comment: +1 I show other form elements based upon the selected value. So setting the default in the object as shown in this solution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: You were right, I did have an empty object initialized! Changed that and it worked, thanks :)