# Getting the current month by default in a dropdownlist

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working in a project where the user on the first visit can see the content of the current month by default.
But if they want to see contents of another month they need to select month and year from dropdown list.

```
<div class="row" ng-show="firstVisit">
        <div class="col">
            <select ng-init="item1=m+1" ng-model="item1" ng-change="onchangeMonth()" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                    <option style="text-indent:30%" ng-repeat="item1 in IdeaMonthList" value="{{item1}}" >{{item1}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-hide="firstVisit">
        <div class="col">
            <select ng-model="item1" ng-change="onchangeMonth()" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                    <option style="text-indent:30%" ng-repeat="item1 in IdeaMonthList" value="{{item1}}" >{{item1}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

if user is visited for the 1st time it should show current month details,i am able to get the contents but the the month selected is not coming in dropdown.

```
$scope.firstVisit=true;
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMonth();
var IdeaMonth=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
$scope.IdeaMonthList=IdeaMonth;
$rootScope.MonthSelected=m+1;
$scope.onchangeMonth = function() {
        selectedValue=$scope.item1;
        $rootScope.MonthSelected = selectedValue;
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ng-shows that will be displayed if firstVisit is `true`. I suppose one of them should be `ng-show=!firstVisit`?

And don't you have a plunker to demonstrate what the problem is? The default month is not selected in the dropdown, that's the problem?

Comment: dont look at those two firstVist.I just want the current month selected in dropdown list when the user open that page.

Comment: Your example code is very confusing, but you are definitely doing something wrong. You should not use ng-init to initialize your item1.

Your ng-repeat should look like `ng-repeat="item in IdeaMonthList"` and in your angularapp you should initialize item1 with the value of the current month.

Answer (score -1):

Should your `$scope.item1 = m+1` OR `$scope.item1 = $rootScope.MonthSelected`

However, you dont need to use `$rootScope` for storing the month.

Comment: I didnt get you.When firstVisit =true,in dropdown list the value should come as m+1,but its coming as 1 everytime.

Comment: ng-model for the dropdown is item1, so if you set the value of the model to m+1, it should work. Please try it out.

Comment: i tried it out,its not working.You can get a reference to my question through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722578/select-default-option-not-working-with-ionic-framework.  In that link that options are static so that guy can use option selected but in mine options are dynamic using ng-repeat.